# Mapping through a list of items in react and editing each item separately issue

Tags: reactjs, forms, edit

I am working on a list of items that I get from an API. It is rendered properly. But, I rendered a button in each item of the list on which you click, and then, the item turns into a form of inputs as many as the number of elements in the item in order to make it editable. I have tried the following code but once I click on the button, it turns all items into a form of inputs instead of turning only the item that I clicked on :

```
{orderWithID.data.order_items.map((item, index, array) => {
                                            if (!isEditActive) {
                                                {
                                                    return <tr>
                                                        <td>#{item.index}</td>
                                                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                                                        <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                                                        <td>{item.price}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div className="delete-items-wrapper">
                                                                <div>-</div>
                                                                <div className="edit-delete-items">
                                                                    <img className="edit-img" src={edit} 
                                                                        onClick={() => {
                                                                        setEditActive(!isEditActive);

                                                                    }
                                                                    }
                                                                    />
                                                                    {index > 0 ? <div className="recycle- 
                                                                    bin"><img src={recycle_bin} onClick= 
                                                                    {() => {
                                                                        
                                                                     postRemoveItem(orderWithID.data._id, 
                                                                     item._id);
                                                                        
                                                                   loadOrderWithID(orderWithID.data._id);
                                                                    }} /></div> : null}
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                { return <div>
                                              <Form>
                                                  <input type="text" name="name"/>
                                                  <input type="text" name="price"/>
                                                  <input type="text" name="quantity"/>
                                                  <input type="text" name="instructions"/>                                              
                                              </Form>
                                             </div> }
                                            }
```

How can I edit that part to achieve what I actually want!? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `isEditActive` to be equal to the index of the current iteration in the array like this `setEditActive(index)` and for your if check do this `if (isEditActive === index) {` this should make only the current form visible.